# How to use Path Parameters in AWS Lambda POJO handler

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pojo

I'm trying to utilize both the http body and a path param in my POJO handler. How do I access the path params when I don't currently have an event object?

My handler looks something like this:

```
@Override
public Object handleRequest(MyCustomModel model, Context context) {
  // Doing stuff with model that was deserialized in request body
  // but need path param '/some/path/{id}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you're better off handling the event object yourself. To do that, configure the API gateway with a lambda proxy integration for your lambda, then populate your custom model object yourself based on the contents of the event body and path parameters.

Here's an [excerpt from an example in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-java) that shows how to read the event object:

```
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log("Loading Java Lambda handler of ProxyWithStream");


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
    String name = "you";
    String city = "World";
    String time = "day";
    String day = null;
    String responseCode = "200";

    try {
        JSONObject event = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
        if (event.get("queryStringParameters") != null) {
            JSONObject qps = (JSONObject)event.get("queryStringParameters");
            if ( qps.get("name") != null) {
                name = (String)qps.get("name");
            }
        }

        if (event.get("pathParameters") != null) {
            JSONObject pps = (JSONObject)event.get("pathParameters");
            if ( pps.get("proxy") != null) {
                city = (String)pps.get("proxy");
            }
        }

        if (event.get("headers") != null) {
            JSONObject hps = (JSONObject)event.get("headers");
            if ( hps.get("day") != null) {
                day = (String)hps.get("day");
            }
        }

        if (event.get("body") != null) {
            JSONObject body = (JSONObject)parser.parse((String)event.get("body"));
            if ( body.get("time") != null) {
                time = (String)body.get("time");
            }
        }
...
```